# Time-Energy commutation in Generalized Uncertainty Principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-gravity, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Several versions of Generalized Uncertainty Principle (GUP) has been proposed recently. Does anyone know the status of time-energy commutation rule in these theories? How [t,E] has been modified?

Comment: Do you have a publication (or publications?) on the matter?

Comment: Here you will get a review:
Page 6-7
http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02436 
However I am not sure if I am allowed to insert i=j=0 in equations [28]-[38] hence asking if anyone has encountered such [t,E] relations explicitly anywhere.

Comment: Typically one uses $i,j$ indices to denote *spatial* coordinates only, so I would suspect not. I also don't see any indication of the authors of that paper mentioning $[\Delta E,\Delta t]$, though I've only done a brief skimming.